# How can I see kubernetes limitrange 403 forbidden errors

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Apparently when I set a limitrange on pod/container resources in my namespace, the limitranger will check all requests for resources. According to the documentation

```
If creating or updating a resource (Pod, Container, 
PersistentVolumeClaim) violates a limit range constraint,
the request to the API server will fail with HTTP status code 403 FORBIDDEN
and a message explaining the constraint that would have been violated.
```

How do I see these errors? After deploying the limitrange I use kubectl to scale down, and then back up my deployment. When I do 'get pods' I see that the new pods were not created. Performing the scale up resulted in no output apart from '[deployment name] scaled'

(For the record, I'm not asking how the limitrange works, just how to see these messages. The deployment is quite complicated so there are a few possible things that could be going wrong)

Comment: Hi check the events, `kubectl get events `

Comment: 'no resources found', including with when I use the namespace :/

Comment: yea, events have limited time. after certain amount of time they are stale and remvoed

Comment: what if you do `kubectl describe deploy %deploymentname%`? it should show latest events for the deployment

Comment: @SureshVishnoi even directly after rescaling, there are no events to see.

Comment: @4c74356b41 When viewing the events on the deployment, I see the scale up and scale down events, but nothing else, no error or any indication that the scale up failed

Comment: try and examine the replicate set

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks, that did the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in these case the errors can be found be examining the replica set tied to the deployment with the following:

```
kubectl describe replicaset %name%
```